# Reading two text files and using values from both files to call an API in Python

Tags: python, file, for-loop

I'm trying to read two text files and use values from both as parameters to call an API. I'm having an issue with doing this effectively.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def read_addresses(self):
    f = open("addresses.txt", "r")
    f2 = open("cities.txt", "r")
    self.addresses = f.readlines()
    self.cities = f2.readlines()


def get_data(self):

    for x in self.addresses:
        sep = '  Placeholder'
        self.k = x.split(sep, 1)[0]
        self.k = re.sub('\s+',' ', self.k)


    for x in self.cities:
        sep = '  Placeholder'
        self.j = x.split(sep, 1)[0]
        self.j = re.sub('\s+', ' ', self.j)
        self.city_state = self.j + ',' + ' TX'

        try:
            params = (
                ('address1', self.k
            ),
                ('address2', self.city_state),
            )

            print params
```

**Input (cities.txt)**

```
Unique City 1
Unique City 2
Unique City 3
```

**Input (addresses.txt)**

```
Unique Address 1
Unique Address 2
Unique Address 3
```

**And the output:**

```
(('address1', 'Unique Address 3'), ('address2', 'Unique City 1 , TX'))
(('address1', 'Unique Address 3'), ('address2', 'Unique City 2 , TX'))
(('address1', 'Unique Address 3'), ('address2', 'Unique City 3, TX'))
```

**The output I desire:**

```
(('address1', 'Unique Address 1'), ('address2', 'Unique City 1, TX'))
(('address1', 'Unique Address 2'), ('address2', 'Unique City 2, TX'))
(('address1', 'Unique Address 3'), ('address2', 'Unique City 3, TX'))
```

What is the most effective way to approach this? I'd like to do it in one `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that your first for loop is running completely before you reference *self.k*. What this does is iterates through *self.addresses* and sets *self.k* each time, but when you reference *self.k* in the for loop below it will only hold the value of the last thing in the list because it isn't being iterated through at the same time.

If you want to iterate through both lists at the same time you can do it like this

```
f = open("addresses.txt", "r")
f2 = open("cities.txt", "r")
self.addresses = f.readlines()
self.cities = f2.readlines()
for i,j in zip(self.addresses, self.cities):
    print i
    print j
    print (i, j)
```

This way you won't run into the issue of setting self.k to the final value in the list.

On another note you might want to consider condensing this into a single function and avoiding the use of global variables or class attributes where they aren't necessary. This looks like temporary data that doesn't need to be passed between classes or class methods. I would suggest an approach where within a single function you instantiate and reference variables within the scope of that function and then return or print the desired data. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to

`self.k`

Is the last value from the first for loop. To get your desired output you'll need to store self.k in say a list on every iteration, eg k.append(..)

I don't see how you'll get away with just a single for loop when iterating over 2 lists, though.